# Google scripts : Is there a way to have a getRange with multiples columns no adjacent

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get multiples columns in a sheet and copy it in another.
With the [getRange function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns), is there a way to get and copy (for example) : 
Col1, Col3, Col7 ? (And I'm not really happy to use a query for this...)

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do to use this is to put the columns that you want to copy into an array like this [1,3,7] and let that be the first parameter for the copyColumns function.  To facilitate it's use creating an intermediate function relieves you from having to do that in your code.  But both functions must be present in your code.

```
function copySelectedColumns()
{
  copyColumns([1,3,7],'mysrc','mydes');
}

function copyColumns(columns,src,dest)
{
  var columns=(typeof(columns)!='undefined')?columns:'';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(src);
  var ds=ss.getSheetByName(dest);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var uA=[];
  if(columns.length)
  {
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      uA[i]=[];
      for(var j=0;j<vA[0].length;j++)
      {
        if(columns.indexOf(j+1)>-1)
        {
          uA[i][uA[i].length]=vA[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
    ds.getRange(1,1,uA.length,uA[0].length).setValues(uA);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks you for the tips !